# HTTP403 Error urllib2.urlopen(URL)

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I am trying to open the URL to parse for content using the following code. but I receive a 403 error when i try through python and not while using the same URL through a web browser. any help to overcome this?

```
import urllib2
URL = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=something%20unusual'
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
```

**Response from Py Interpreter: HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is using User-Agent filtering to prevent bots from interacting with its search service.  You can observe this by comparing these results with `curl(1)` and optionally using the `-A` flag to change the User-Agent string:

```
$ curl -I 'http://www.google.com/search?q=something%20unusual'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
...

$ curl -I 'http://www.google.com/search?q=something%20unusual' -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

You should probably instead be using the [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) service to automate Google searches.  Alternatively, you could set your own User-Agent header with the `urllib2` library (instead of the default of something like `"Python-urllib/2.6"`), but this may contravene Google's terms of service.

Answer (score 3):

`User-Agent` header is the one giving you problem. Seems to me the web page forbid any request made from a non browser by checking the `User-Agent` header.  The key is setting a `User-Agent` that simulates a browser in python.

This worked for me:

```
In [1]: import urllib2

In [2]: URL = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=something%20unusual'

In [4]: opener = urllib2.build_opener()

In [5]: opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

In [6]: response = opener.open(URL)

In [7]: response
Out[7]: <addinfourl at 47799472 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x02D7F5B0>>

In [8]: response.read()
```

Hope this helps!